# Error creating bean, NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: java, spring

I have bean definition in my xml file

```
<bean id="userDao" class="xyz.UserDAOImpl">
<property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
</bean>
```

and when I start my server I get this error :
Error creating bean with name 'userDao' defined in class
path resource [xyz/configuration.xml]:
Initialization of bean failed;
nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class com.sun.proxy.$Proxy178

This is a multi-module application and I don't have access to all parts of this project.
I tried adding cglib, but it still doesn't work

Comment: Could you please post the dao and the pom, if any?

Comment: I don't have it now, but I'll post it tomorrow.

Answer (score 0):

This error is caused often if you are trying to inject implementation instead of interface. I mean check whether you are not trying to inject the UserDAOImpl instead of the UserDAO. E.g:

```
@Resource("userDao")
private transient UserDAO userDAO;
```

and not

```
private transient UserDAOImpl userDAO;
```

probably this could fix your problem.